# Trouble connecting to Docker application via subdirectory instead of port

Tags: docker, iis, web-hosting

Preface: I'm new to the whole web hosting thing, so I apologize if any information I give doesn't make sense or is inaccurate. I will do my best to explain things.

I currently have a self-hosted server running Windows Server 2019 that is hosting two sites via IIS. I recently have created an application that runs on a Docker container instance that hosts a website on port 40444. I would like to access this site via a specific subdirectory on my website instead of the port (`www.mywebsite.com/website3` instead of `www.mywebsite.com:40444`). For clarification, here is an example of what I'm looking to do:

> - [www.mywebsite.com/website1](http://www.mywebsite.com/website1) (hosted on IIS)
> - [www.mywebsite.com/website2](http://www.mywebsite.com/website2) (hosted on IIS)
> - [www.mywebsite.com/website3](http://www.mywebsite.com/website3) (hosted on docker via port 40444)

I was able to get a basic reverse proxy set up and successfully got the docker application to show on localhost/, but I would prefer using a subdirectory if possible.(image below).

[image]

I attempted to change `(.*)` to `(.*)website3$` and it did what I wanted, but the website cannot load any files (i.e css, js, etc.) and gives me the following error
`https://www.mywebsite.com/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

If IIS isn't the best option to accomplish what I need I am more than happy to use a different solution. As I mentioned before, I'm new to web hosting and it was just the simplest to set up.

Comment: I was able to get a basic reverse proxy set up and successfully got the docker application to show on localhost. Edit the question to show what you did. Usually you just need to change a few regular expressions, so before changing things further that's the topic you should learn from a search engine.

Comment: Apologies. I changed some wording and added an image showing the inbound rule for the reverse proxy

Comment: You really need to learn more about regular expressions so that in the future you don't rely on others. Now give `^website3/(.*)$` a try.

Comment: This link should help you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr).